# Does any Marvel superhero have a no kill policy?

Tags: marvel

In the DC universe, most famously Batman has a 'no kill policy'. But so far every Marvel superhero I know has killed one way or the other.

So, is there any superhero in the Marvel universe who practices a no kill policy?

I don't want superheroes who avoid killing, but a superhero who has specifically said that he won't kill since it's in his moral code.

Answers from the movies, comics and tv shows are acceptable.

Comment: The punisher for sure.

Comment: Not Aunt May; https://www.reddit.com/r/Spiderman/comments/7ha3cd/this_comic_where_aunt_may_kills_a_spiderman/

Comment: You need to define what you mean by a "no kill policy" very clearly. Must a hero be unwilling to kill under any circumstances whatsoever, and apply this rule all the time? Does it count if that's almost -- but not quite -- always applicable? Or what if a hero simply believes in not killing except when it's the only way to prevent one or more other people dying? There are plenty of heroes who fall into the latter category. And I'm not sure if any, including Batman, fall into the first one. Some versions of Batman have killed people.

Comment: @LogicDictates, logic does dictate!!, I mean in a fashion very similar to bale's batman where he had chances to kill but did not, like to the point where he didnt kill joker and the joker made him question his ethics and he even stopped catwoman from killing, there was ra's al ghul tho.

Comment: I know every hero has killed somehow, but lets just go with the basic definition of no kill policy ie I wont kill (coz it will make me like the enemy). where they had a dilemma where they started questioning if he(the villain) should even live or not and if they are doing the right thing by not killing

Comment: Like I said, there are plenty of heroes who seem to hate the idea of killing, and would try to avoid doing it, or allowing anyone else to do it, under almost all circumstances. If that counts as a "no kill policy," then we could have a pretty long list here (Spider-Man, Superman, Captain America, etc). If the policy has to be no killing, ever, no matter what, though, then I'm not sure any hero has a policy like that as the norm. Spider-Man did insist that no one would die when he's around for a while, but eventually realised that was impractical, and abandoned that claim.

Comment: This is why we need proper superhero primary hustings, so each superhero can clearly set out their vigilante policies in details. We tried to negotiate it into the Sokovia Accords, but the delegation from Latveria were really intransigent on the issue.

Comment: @A.bakker The Punisher definitely has a no kill policy. Oops, I was missing some punctuation. It's a "no, kill" policy.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The only one I know for sure is Spider-man. There are many instances of him refusing to kill enemies, even asking heroes he teams up with to do the same. He has also been shown to often hold back his full abilities, having been able to brutally injure some of his opponents when he loses control.

This rule stems from the death of Uncle Ben, he made a vow to save people, his enemies included.

While there have been a few exceptions to this rule over the years, in general this is something he still follows.

**Carnage USA**

[image: Carnage USA]

**Maximum Carnage**

[image: Maximum Carnage]

**Morbius the Living Vampire**

[image: Morbius the Living Vampire]

Comment: Spider-Man has killed a bunch of people and just shrugged it off; https://spiderfan.org/faq/killed.html#:~:text=Deliberately%20killed%20the%20Finisher%20by,missile%20back%20to%20his%20tank.&text=Accidentally%20killed%20Gwen%20Stacy%2C%20snapping,death%2C%20thrown%20by%20Norman%20Osborn. His 'no-kill' policy is very similar to Superman's in that he talks a big game when it suits the writers, then periodically kills people.

Comment: Just because someone breaks a code they have, doesn't mean they don't try their hardest to live by it. In that list, most of them say 'accidentally' or they die in some sort of vague/unexpected way. He might have broken it once or twice but over the many years, Spider-Man has maintained this personal code.

Comment: @knightwatch - By my count, he's killed at least half a dozen people intentionally, let alone accidentally.

Comment: @Valorum No you’re right and Im not trying to say Spider-Man has never killed anyone. Im just saying breaking a self imposed rule or code a few times does not negate its existence. If a vegetarian eats a hamburger once or twice, they can still call themselves a vegetarian. Even Batman has killed a couple times over the years yet everyone always refers to his ‘No-Kill’ rule.

Comment: @Valorum In the list you linked, the only one that seem fair to count are the punisher and modular-man. The others are magicians that die as an unforeseen result of Spider-Man meddling with their magic, enemies that commit suicide because they failed their attack on spider-man, and collateral damage while spider-man is diverting a missile in a desperate attempt to reduce the number of victims. The second in the list is Gwen Stacy?! She was killed by Norman Osborn, not Spider-Man!

Comment: @Stef - It's not an exhaustive list. Also he could just as easily have diverted the missile elsewhere.

Comment: @Valorum Every comic book hero ever depends on the writer.  Every comic book hero ever will have examples of failing to follow some core aspect of their character in at least some of their iterations as a result.  Truth is you simply cannot get a comprehensive understanding of a comic book hero if you insist in including every comic because they can change so much depending on who writes them and are not 100% consistent.  Best you can do is ask what the majority of writers stay consistent to.  Any standard higher then that makes describing a hero's belief and values impossible to manage.

Comment: @dsollen - And well that may be largely true, killing *multiple* people is an act of such enormity that we cannot simply brush it under the carpet as 'early episode weirdness'.

Comment: Which storylines/issues are these pictures taken from? I recognise the second set as *Maximum Carnage* but not the others.

Comment: @AJM The first one is from Carnage USA. and I believe the last one is from a Morbius comic although I dont remember which one.

Comment: Though I have accepted your answer, I have realized that the extent of the no kill policy ultimately depends on the writer of the comic and what he wants.

Comment: Meanwhile, Japanese Spider-Man: https://i.imgur.com/Djo7dNn.jpg

Answer (score 6):

Daredevil is Catholic and as a large part of that he has a no-kill rule.

It's a large plot point of the Netflix adaptation of Daredevil.

Comment: The comic version of Daredevil [has killed](https://www.cbr.com/people-daredevil-murdered/) on occasion, though. Most of the examples listed on that page are non-canon to the main comic universe or otherwise dubious, but the examples numbered 14, 13 and 2 are legit and canon.

Comment: when facing the Punisher, Daredevil also occasionally stops him from killing a few baddies. I'll have to double check, I think it's in "Welcome back, Frank"

Comment: @LogicDictates: even though "Thou shalt not kill" is part of Catholic doctrine, Catholics have killed in the name of Catholicism quite a few times.

Comment: @Taladris - It's also worth remembering that Daredevil is a lawyer who strongly believes in the legal system. By virtue of that, it makes sense that he believes killing is justifiable in circumstances where it's permitted under the law, i.e. to prevent oneself or others from being murdered. It also explains why he's so opposed to the Punisher's methods; it's not so much that he objects to killing in all circumstances, but rather, he objects to the idea of criminals being denied due process.

Answer (score 4):

In [Maximum Carnage](https://www.marvel.com/comics/events/151/maximum_carnage), Spider-man stops Firestar from killing Carnage. I don't have the exact panel, but he basically asks himself "What Would Captain America Do" as he looks for a solution that doesn't result in Carnage's death.

In [Amazing Spider-Man #655](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/35517/amazing_spider-man_1999_655) Spidey vows "No one dies". He even goes out of his way to spare the villain [Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massacre_(Marvel_Comics))

Comment: Cap be like yeah, don’t tell the kid about all the Nazis I wasted in WW2.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite  There was an issue where Captain America killed to save lives and it was a major blow to his image as well as deeply personally troubling.  This did, indeed, inspire fans to snipe that he had killed during WWII, but that was how he was portrayed.

Answer (score 3):

Spider-Man's "no kill rule" is a crucial plot point of the MCU movie *No Way Home*. In the movie, several Spider-Man villains from other universes are drawn to the "main" MCU universe and attack Spider-Man. Not only does Spider-Man try to catch them without killing them but it turns out that

> if Spider-Man sends them back to their respective universes, they will return at the time of their death.

Spider-Man goes out of his way to change this and save them. Note that (spoilers for *Homecoming* and *Far From Home*)

> the Vulture ended up in jail in *Homecoming* while Mysterio gets killed accidentally by one of his drones.

Comment: Ironically though, despite the efforts he made to save those villains, he did still try to kill someone in this film.

Comment: @LogicDictates: He was not in his right mind at the time, and he was talked out of doing it by more mature Spiderman